# Open folders in jstree by just one click

Tags: jquery, html, css, jstree

We have a jstree in our web page.
It has items and folders.
Items are in folders. each folder has a sign to open folder and show its items. another way to open folder is double click on it. how we can open a folder by 1 click?
jsTree is here :
https://www.jstree.com/

Comment: Provide a working example...

Comment: Items are in folders. each folder has a sign to open folder and show its items. another way to open folder is double click on it. how we can open a folder by 1 click?

Comment: This is not a working example...

Answer (score -1):

You can open all your nodes using the "open_all" event. you can learn more at the oficial documentation: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=open_all&f=open_all.jstree

```
$('#tree').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) { 
    $('#tree').jstree('open_all');
});
```

In this example "#tree" is the selector for your tree id and you can change the "select_node" event for any other event.

Comment: Items are in folders. each folder has a sign to open folder and show its items. another way to open folder is double click on it. how we can open a folder by 1 click?